# CGI serving HTML not rendering

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have CGI python program serving HTML as content (not URL).  The flow is:

```
1. open http://jioworld.jioconnect.com/cgi-bin/loginpp.py
2. you get HTML form (since you have not yet login)
3. enter some dummy user and password and submit
4. you stay on same page after submit even though response html is served. So the page (response) is not rendered by browser but cookie is set
5. reload the page (hit refresh/reload)
6. page is rendered
```

My issue is: why page is not rendered in step 4 and on reload it is rendering in step 6.

I expect step 4 to render page.

I have experimented with relative, absolute urls for all links like stylesheet, javascript, images etc. but seems that only absolute ones seem to work better than others.  This is again issue because I also tried BASE tag of html set to / and it does not work.  The images etc. resolve to cgi-bin/images instead of /images.  So I set BASE all URLs to absolute possible causing BASE tag to be ignored.  As such I then set BASE tag also full URL for host.

Answer (score 0):

> The images etc. resolve to cgi-bin/images instead of /images.

That's easily fixed. When the server runs your script it sets the scripts's current working directory (CWD) to cgi-bin. I believe that it's a common convention for servers to do that, although I suspect there's an Apache config to change it.

I haven't used Apache for a few years, so I'm a bit rusty, but I occasionally play with a couple of basic Web servers. One of these servers starts the script in cgi-bin, the other starts it in the server's CWD, so I put this in my CGI scripts:

```
#Change to parent dir if we're in cgi-bin,
if os.path.basename(os.getcwd()) == 'cgi-bin':
    os.chdir('../')
```

But I'm not sure how to solve your problem with step 4 in your list.

Normally, you'd send some content like this

`'<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=%s">' % href`

to the browser, where `url` is the page's url. But I don't know if that will work for you.

Perhaps it would help if we could see you CGI script, or at least a reduced version that illustrates the problem.